# Animate UISearchBar slide from top under nav bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, uianimation

I want to add a `UISearchBar` to the bottom of my `UINavigationBar` and I want to make it look like it is a part of the bar. In the video below it shows a default animation of the nav bar sliding into the view from the top. I want to slide in the search bar just before that and make it look like one object.

How can I re-create this animation for a `UISearchBar` for the showing and hiding animation? And make it seamlessly animate?

[Animation](http://youtu.be/vETYIWs3hVE)

Comment: Provide us the code about what you tried until now, it will be easier for us to deal with

Answer (score 0):

I think you use a custom animation for navigation bar not default animation.

My test code is following.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
// Add a UISearchBar below navigation bar in Interface Builder 
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;

@end

@implementation ViewController{

    // this is flag for navigation bar status (shown or hidden)
    BOOL _isNaviBarHidden;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    _isNaviBarHidden = NO;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


// trigger for show navigation bar. I don't know when you want to show. so I add a button in my test viewcontroller
- (IBAction)showNavibar:(id)sender {


    if(_isNaviBarHidden == NO){

        return;
    }


    [self setNavibarAndSearchBarHidden:NO];

}



- (IBAction)hideNavibar:(id)sender {

    if(_isNaviBarHidden == YES){

        return;
    }

    [self setNavibarAndSearchBarHidden:YES];
}


-(void)setNavibarAndSearchBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden{


    CGFloat yOffset = -130;

    CALayer *naviBarLayer = self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer;
    CALayer *searchBarLayer = self.searchBar.layer;


    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{

        if(hidden){

            naviBarLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform(CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, yOffset));
            searchBarLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform(CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, yOffset));


        }else{

            naviBarLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform(CGAffineTransformIdentity);
            searchBarLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform(CGAffineTransformIdentity);

        }


    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        _isNaviBarHidden = hidden;

    }];


}
```